# Не могу никак нстроить sass в webstorm, очень прошу помощи)

Tags: css, scss, sass, webstorm

Всем привет, не могу никак настроить компиляцию scss в css в webstorm, помогите пожалуйста это решить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]